# Creating a copy of a PFObject

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfobject, nscopying

I am in a situation where I allow the user to download a `PFObject` and modify it locally, and they can then either cancel the changes or hit Done, which will dismiss the editing interface but NOT upload the changes to Parse yet. They need to hit Save on the previous screen to write all changes to the database at once.

The problem is once the `PFObject` is modified, you cannot revert it to its prior state without refetching from the database. But I cannot always refetch the data from the database every time they hit Cancel because the prior state may not be uploaded to Parse yet (and that's a bad UX making them wait to discard changes that are only stored locally).

For example, imagine the user taps to edit the `PFObject`, they make changes then hit Done, then tap on it again and further edit the object, then hit Cancel. In this case, the object needs to be reverted to its prior state, but that state has not been uploaded to Parse yet. So I cannot refetch the data from the database to revert changes otherwise it would overwrite the changes they made the first time.

To solve this problem, I would simply fetch the `PFObject` and store a copy of it. I'd call that the transient object. I would have another property that stores the real object. The user would modify the transient object, and when they hit Cancel I would simply set that to `nil`, if they instead hit Done I would set the real object equal to the transient object, and once they finally hit Save I would save the real object to the database. That way I can be sure changes aren't being made to the real object until the user commits the changes. The problem is, `PFObject` does not adopt the `NSCopying` protocol (not sure why), therefore I cannot create a copy of the `PFObject`. Any change I make to it affects the real object.

How can this be resolved, without modifying the app's design that allows control over when the data is committed and later saved? Is there a way to extend `PFObject` and adopt `NSCopying`, has it been done before?

I did consider storing the attributes of the object in a dictionary and allow the user to edit that instead, then upon commit set each of those attributes on the `PFObject`. The problem with this solution arises with complex structures. In this app, I allow the user to modify multiple arrays that contain multiple `PFObject`s. It's just infeasible to try to recreate and later merge changes with complex structures like this beyond a single simple `PFObject`.

Comment: The approach I use is to store changes in local variables and update the actual PFObject values when save is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same problem.  I did not make any changes directly to the PFObject, but rather, saved the updates in an NSDictionary.  When the user clicks the done button, I then update the PFObject and `saveInBackground`.  I don't think there is a "discard local changes" option for PFObject.  If you don't do this, the only option is to throw out the existing PFObject and fetch again.

Regarding the `NSDictionary` comment, perhaps `NSArray` would be better.  The implementation really depends on your specific program, but I'll give a quick example.  The `NSArray` we'll call `instructionArray`.  Imagine there are 3 sections in a tableView.  Also assume that the data source for each section is an `NSArray` of `PFObjects`.  Now say you want to set the `age` property of each PFObject in Section 2 to 35.

Add an `NSArray` object (corresponding to an instruction to carry out) to the `instructionArray`.  This instruction to carry out could have the form

1. Section to update
2. Property to update
3. Value to update to

So the object you'll add is `@[@(2),@"age",@(35)];`

Given that the user is probably carrying out a finite amount of instructions, it might not be that performance heavy to loop through the `instructionArray` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so when a cell uses its corresponding `PFObject` to figure out what to display, it can loop through the instructions after and change what is displayed as if the `PFObject` was updated.

When the save button is touched, loop through the instructions and actually edit the `PFObjects` themselves.

If you need the instructions to handle specific objects rather than sections, then you just have to update the structure of the `instructionArray`.  Maybe you could include an identifier to indicate what type of instruction it is.

Comment: I just added a paragraph at the end of my question stating why the dictionary approach doesn't work for this app, and refetching would discard all changes from previous editing sessions which doesn't work in this setup either.

Comment: At risk of you getting really mad at me for pushing the NSDictionary approach, would it be possible to instead record the *actions* in the dictionary rather than the objects themselves.  When the done button is saved, execute those actions on the batches.  And in terms of the UI, have the objects be displayed, but use the actions to update the UI further until the save button is touched.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by actions, perhaps you could update the answer with an example. In this case the user could add `PFObject`s to the arrays at any index, modify attributes of the object at any index in the arrays, or delete any existing objects in the arrays.